# Oracle column with Timestamp(6) data type extract using ssis

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, ssis, timestamp

I am trying to pull an oracle table data into sql server using SSIS. I have a package variable that holds the source query that needs to be fired in the oracle db.I have a data flow task with oledb source(oracle) and oledb destination(sql server).

The oledb source query(variable) is as follows

```
Select A,B,C 
  From "Table" TT  
 Where C in (Select coalesce(ab,cd) as c 
               From "Table" T2 
              Where Last_Upd_Dt >= '2018-09-24 12:00:00')
```

The column `Last_Upd_Dt`  is a `TimeStamp(6)` with default value of `LocalTimeStamp` in the source oracle DB

My question is in what format should my input parameter value be so that I dont have to convert the `Last_Upd_Dt` column to `TO_DATE()`, `TO_CHAR()` etc.

If I run that query using SSIS I get

> ***ORA-01843***: *not a valid month*

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
... Where Last_Upd_Dt >= to_date('2018-09-24 12:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

or

```
... Where Last_Upd_Dt >= timestamp'2018-09-24 12:00:00'
```

you may refer the following demonstration :

```
SQL> create table tab ( id int not null, time timestamp(6) default LocalTimeStamp not null );

Table created

SQL> insert into tab(id) values(1);

1 row inserted

SQL> select * from tab t;

ID TIME
-- --------------------------
 1 26/09/2018 08:23:23,068025


SQL> select * from tab where Last_Upd_Dt >= to_date('2018-09-24 12:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');

ID TIME
-- --------------------------
 1 26/09/2018 08:23:23,068025

SQL> select * from tab where Last_Upd_Dt >= timestamp'2018-09-24 12:00:00';

ID TIME
-- --------------------------
 1 26/09/2018 08:23:23,068025


SQL> select * from tab where Last_Upd_Dt >= to_date('2018-09-26 12:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');

ID TIME
-- --------------------------   
                              --> no rows selected
```

Answer (score 1):

[Oracle supports](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm) the `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` keywords.  You can express the logic as:

```
where Last_Upd_Dt >= TIMESTAMP '2018-09-24 12:00:00'
```

If you did not have a time component, you would do:

```
where Last_Upd_Dt >= DATE '2018-09-24'
```